# ordering in a Python module

Tags: python, django

```
 class Images(models.Model):
      job=models.OneToOneField(Jobs)
       image=models.ImageField()
 class Jobs(models.Model):
       picture=models.ForeignKey(Images, null=True)
```

it gives an error on

```
job=models.OneToOneField(Jobs)
```

it because class job define later in the module, but if i change positions of these two classes then it will give me an error on

```
   picture=models.ForeignKey(Images, null=True)
```

What should i do in this case?(without put classes in different modules)

Comment: can you forward declare the class ?

Comment: @MortenJensen Forward declarations don't exist in Python (the whole concept doesn't even make sense).

Comment: That answer, I thought, was right, wasn't it?  I altered the order of my ForeignKeys on my site as a test and it worked.  The answer was remove `job=models.OneToOneField(Jobs)` and after the Jobs class, add `Images.job = models.OneToOneField(Jobs)`

Comment: @delnan I know, I was thinking more in the lines of just creating the class like so: `class blahblah(models.Model): pass` or something :) I didn't mean forward declarations in the C++ sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a string with the class name to instantiate the first model before the other has been created:

```
class Images(models.Model):
    job=models.OneToOneField('Jobs')
    image=models.ImageField()

class Jobs(models.Model):
    picture=models.ForeignKey(Images, null=True)
```

From the [docs on models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself.

Comment: was just gonna post this :)

Comment: Does `Images.job = models.OneToOneField(Jobs)` not work too?

Comment: No it does not, Django has some metaclass magic that requires the fields to be created inside of the class body.